# How to enable "parent ScrollView" when user reaches at the bottom or top of "child WebView" scroll using Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, webview, scrollview

I have a **WebView** inside a **ScrollView**, such as:

```xml
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.example.TouchyWebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="600dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have implemented **TouchyWebView** extending **WebView** and the code is given below:

```java
public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

    public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Now, what I want are:

**Point 1:** When the user scrolls the child **WebView**, only this **WebView** will be scrolled (which I have performed implementing **TouchyWebView**).

**Point 2:** When the user reaches at the bottom or top of the child **WebView** scroll, the parent **ScrollView** will start to work although the user is touching or scrolling the child **WebView** (which I could not implement).

Now, how can I achieve the functionality described in "**Point 2**"?